# Magento soap api shoppingCartCreate with quote_currency_code arguments

Tags: api, magento, soap, parameters, cart

I'm trying to magento API cartorder with Soap, but am stuck with shoppingCartCreate with quote_currency_code arguments, shoppingCartCreate supports only two arguments like sessionId and storeId? kindly help me to create quoteId with corresponding currency code.

---

```
  $cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate(array('sessionId' => $sessionId, 'store' => $store_id,'quote_currency_code'=>$currency_code);
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @toti08 Code added.